# show $u(x,y)=\Re[f(z)]$ is bounded when it has an upper bound using lousvilles theorem and $e^f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

suppose that $f(z)$ is entire and that harmonic function $u(x,y)=\Re [f(z)] $ has an upperbound $u_0$ that is $u(x,y) \leq u_0 $ $ $\forall x, y in $ XY plane

show $u(x,y) $ must be constant throught the plane

suggestion ] apply loiusville's theorem  to function $g(z)=exp(f(z))$

---

Loiusville's theorem

f is bounded and entire on $\mathbb{C}$  then $f(z)$ is constant thourght the complex plane

---

$$|g(z)|=|e^{u(x,y)+iv(x,y)}|=|e^{u(x,y)}e^{iv(x,y)}|=|e^u||e^{iv}|=|e^u|*1<e^{u_0}$$

so $g(z)$ is bounded  it is also entire then it is a constant

Not sure how this applies to showing that $u(x,y)$ is bounded guessing that it has not establish that it has a lower bound. somehow the suggestion should imply that??????

**I know that this is aduplicate dont want to reach out to someone that ask this question years ago**
appreciate help alot thanks

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is entire and non-constant, then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Y is dense in X if $\bar {Y}=X$. that is the closure of Y is X . I dont see how that shows that u is bonded from there. if it was compact it would be closed and bounded in reals not too sure on complex plane. But I think it still applies in C

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, you know that $f$ is entire and $u=\Re f$ is bounded, and want to show that $u$ is constant. Since $u$ is bounded, say by $0<u_0<\infty$, then $f(\mathbb{C})\subset \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |\Re z|\le u_0\}$, and hence cannot be dense. As such, $f$ is constant (and therefore, so is $u$).

Comment: I can show that f is a constant with lousville theorem and stuff on the question. not to comfortable with density though I should because I have a real analisis test.. anyways can;'t make the leap that f is constant so $u(x,y)$ also is

Comment: The implication $f$ entire and non-constant $\implies$ $f(\mathbb{C})$ dense is proven using Liouville's theorem (a nice exercise). 
If $f(z)=\alpha$ for all $z$, then surely $u(z)=\Re f(z)=\Re \alpha$ for all $z$.

Comment: how about this the e^u is bounded , compact? the its preimage is compact closed and bounded that is u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is constant, which implies $|g| = e^u$ is constant. Since $x \to e^x$ is injective on the reals, $u$ is constant.